# Understand grid in caret using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

What it means len in this code, this is the way in that caret build the grid, and i dont know how the len is selected.

```
function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
if(search == "grid") {
out <- expand.grid(degree = seq(1, min(len, 3)),
scale = 10 ^((1:len) - 4),
tau = 2 ^((1:len) - 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Len is set when you call the `train` function. The first thing that happens is this:

`tuneLength = ifelse(trControl$method == "none", 1, 3)`

which in most cases will result in 3. Later on when tuneGrid is called this code is used:

```
tuneGrid <- models$grid(x = predict(ppObj, x), y = y, 
        len = tuneLength, search = trControl$search)
```

As you can see here len is filled with the value from tuneLength. Which is used to fill the len part of grid function of the model.